# Can't click on a button, while an other button is active

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

I made a button, when you click on, it calls a function, which has a big for loop. While the for is active, you can't click any other thing in the window. I want to make a STOP/EXIT button, when you click on, it exits the program (System.exit(0)). But while the for is active, you cant click on them, so basically it is useless.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't have a for loop iterating continuously in a GUI. You can only have algorithms that works within frames (usually within 33 ms).

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your function with a big for loop inside a [thread](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_threads.asp) and [kill the thread](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/killing-threads-in-java/#:%7E:text=A%20thread%20is%20automatically%20destroyed,manage%20the%20execution%20of%20threads.) it when the button is pressed.

Comment: While it would work, it's often used as a poor alternative instead of proper design. Threading has many problems associated with them, such as being dependent on the platform, requiring synchronization, being nondeterministic, etc., when you could just have discrete procedures instead.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I thought that threading is common practice when creating an application with a GUI. How else would you run a computationally intensive task in a GUI application?

Comment: It is if you need to run a computational task asynchronously. I might have misread what the asker was talking about as they talked about an "active state", which sounds like they're not doing computation, but rather some logic. But yes, if they're doing an actual computationally intensive task, then you should use threads.